# Nikon D7100 doesn't recognize firmware update file on SD card

Tags: firmware, nikon-d7100

So I believe I've followed all of the instructions.

I have a D7100, fully charged, on c 1.00 firmware, plugged in, with an approved memory card (SanDisk 16gb SDHC). I put the firmware file on the root of the card, and the firmware menu doesn't give me an upgrade option.

I've tried two memory cards, plugged in, not plugged in. Formatted. Everything I can think of.

No go. Same goes for the distortion control file.

What gives? By all rights it should update. No help so far from Nikon tech support (thank god their tech support is mentally capable of rephrasing the manual to me as though I can't read).

Comment: What do you mean by "plugged in, not plugged in?" You should not connect the camera to the computer via USB at any point in the operation.

Comment: Hope you copied the *.bin file to the root of memory card not the zip file?

Comment: Yes. I copied the bin file to the root of the card.

Comment: Try reseting factory settings and then update

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Create a new folder with an appropriate name on your computer.
> 2. Choose the correct download below for the computer system you are using, and save the download to the folder created in step 1.
> 3. Run the downloaded file to create the folder titled D7100Update, containing the following file: D7100_0101.bin
> 4. Format an approved memory card in the camera, then remove .
> 5. Copy the D7100_0101.bin file to the top level of the memory card using a memory card reader or similar device, do not copy the file
>      into any folder on the memory card.
> 6. Insert memory card into the cameras memory card slot, and switch on.
> 7. Select Firmware Version from the setup menu and follow the instructions displayed to upgrade the camera's firmware.
> 8. DO NOT switch off the camera at any time during the update, doing so may result in the need for service.
> 9. After the upgrade is complete, turn the camera off and remove the memory card.
> 10. Check the cameras firmware version to be sure it completed.

Some users have reported using a card formatted in camera does not work, but that formatting a card in FAT32 using a computer before copying the update file to the card works.

Be sure to run the update file you downloaded to create the file named D7100_0101.bin and only copy that file to the root of the SD card. Copying the downloaded file itself will not work.

At no point in the process should the camera be connected to anything else via the USB or any other ports on the camera. If you try to copy the .bin file to the card while it is inserted in the camera and the camera is connected to the computer via USB, it won't work.

If the camera is attached to a battery grip, remove the grip and use a single battery in the camera. I would even go so far as to disconnect any flash attached to the camera.

Be sure to turn off the camera each time before you remove or insert the memory card in the camera. Also be sure to 'eject' the memory card (via software) on your computer before removing it from the reader.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I have seen those instructions from Nikon. They are the ones I have followed. 

I've got no battery grip or any other attachments other than my lens. I have also, to the best of my memory, switched the camera off between manipulations of the SD card.

RE: Your comment about copying it while the card is in the camera -- Are you actually even able to do that? I'm not (wondering if that indicates a deeper problem with both my memory cards or my camera unit).

Answer (score 3):

What worked in the end was formatting the card on a Windows computer in FAT32 (Happened to be using an external card reader), and copying the file

Comment: How was the card previously formatted?

Comment: Did you just buy an SD card, format it on your computer and then proceed, or was this an SD card that was working in your camera -- i.e. your camera could see it and write photos to it?

Comment: I was having issues too - I followed the Nikon instructions formatting the card in the camera. Still would not update. Answer - format the card as FAT32 or MS DOS FAT in Mac OS or Windows PC and copy the Bin file, worked perfectly. Thanks for the help